# hard to debug error in GWT on IE7 only

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-7

I have a GWT 2.3 app that works fine in IE8 and pretty much every browser version I'm aware of.. but in IE7 I get this... in debug bar I get "unspecified exception"

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107) 
at com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplTrident.setInnerText(DOMImplTrident.java) 
at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element$.setInnerText$(Element.java:621) 
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DirectionalTextHelper.setInnerTextOrHtml(DirectionalTextHelper.java:242) 
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DirectionalTextHelper.setTextOrHtml(DirectionalTextHelper.java:184) 
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label.setText(Label.java:345) 
at com.example.client.ui.DesktopFilter_DesktopFilterUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi
```

it looks like it's happening on the isHtml? line in this generated method... I'm just not sure what to try next... has anyone else already ripped out a bunch of hair on this yet and can save me from it?

```
function $setTextOrHtml(this$static, content_0, isHtml){
  this$static.isSpanWrapped = false;
  isHtml?(this$static.element.innerHTML = content_0 || '' , undefined):(($clinit_189() , this$static.element).innerText = content_0 || '' , undefined);
  if (this$static.textDir != this$static.initialElementDir) {
    this$static.textDir = this$static.initialElementDir;
    setDirectionOnElement(this$static.element, this$static.initialElementDir);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
The generated UI binder code that is making the offending setText() call is below. there is other widget setup code inbetween but nothing that looks relevant to the problem.

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label registerButton 
        = (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label) 
                  GWT.create(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label.class);
```

...snip...

```
registerButton.setText("Create New Account");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhg...

http://groups.google.com/group/cufon/browse_thread/thread/5524963e314b5b32

I think it's just this IE7 standalone thing... I hate supporting IE...